# flask loads app.py file and pages that no longer exist

Tags: python, powershell, winforms, flask, anaconda

I was working with flask on windows. I load flask with `python app.py`. And app.py contains:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then I try to load this page `http://127.0.0.1:5000/new_data_table` and it loads a page eventhough it shouldn't. I used to have this page in my app.py but I wanted to do some debugging but I see that the changes I make in app.py are not being reflected no matter how many times I re-run app.py.

What I see is that flask is loading the code from somewhere else than app.py, from some cache or something probably. But I am not able to find such things or see where to look for. I need to know where flask is getting the code to load the pages.

Output when I make small change in app.py:

```
PS C:\Users\Documents\main> python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 372-211-807
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\main\\.ipynb_checkpoints\\app-checkpoint.py', reloading
 * Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 372-211-807
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\main\\.~app.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\main\\.~app.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\main\\.~app.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\main\\app.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\main\\app.py', reloading
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\main\\.~app.py', reloading
 * Restarting with watchdog (windowsapi)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 372-211-807
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I looked for hidden files, didn't find any. I deleted ipynb-checkpoints and pycache folders, etc.. but found no change.

Edit:

Output to `flask routes`:

```
Endpoint  Methods  Rule
--------  -------  -----------------------
static    GET      /static/<path:filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that we don't see any requests to localhost in your log. You can check all routes of your app via flask with:
`flask routes`
to see what routes are registered in your app